# .htaccess pretty url problem (mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have a directory that lists products by categories. if a `_GET` variable exists, it is used in a query. I would like to use "pretty url's", like: `example/a/1/b/2/c/3/d/4` becomes `example/index.html?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4`

most `.htaccess` examples I see only use variables to replace the `_GET` values, but I can use rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.html?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.html?$1=$2&$3=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.html?$1=$2 [L]
```

And it works... However, the when I add longer and longer `RewriteRules` (like out to `&17=$18`), it stops working. The last variables in the chain turn into some sort of array based on earlier values (in above it would build `index.html?a0=a1&a3=a4`)...

- Is there a better way to do this?
- It seems inefficient?
- Is there a limit to the number of variables in `.htaccess`
- How long a rule can be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite only supports up to `$9` and `%9`.

I recommend you either modify your script to use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, or you use `RewriteMap` to invoke a script to transform the path into a querystring.

Comment: Thank you! Google wasn't turning up any results on how many variables are allowed in .htacces, now I know to try a different direction... will report back.

Answer (score 1):

`mod_rewrite` only allows for you to have ten back-references, one of which is the whole matchable part (which ends up leaving you with only nine definable capture groups), so you're definitely limited by that.

However, to me it would make much more sense to examine the server's `REQUEST_URI`/`SCRIPT_NAME`/`PATH_INFO` variable in your script file, and parse that to get the key-value pairs from the URL. Then, you'd simply have this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

And then your script would take care of the rest. I do have to wonder though, if you have *that* many `GET` variables, is it actually more readable if they're all made into a "pretty" URL? After all, if you have twenty-some forward slashes in the URL, you may be equally well off just passing a normal query string at that point. It depends on your application though and how users interface with these URLs, so you may have good reason for wanting to do it this way.

Comment: Thank you both... I'd started town the REQUEST_URI, and Tim, I'm using your example rule - it is easy to implement (RewriteMaps scarred me!). You're right that though the url's are somewhat prettier, it's not a huge advantage to our customers (especiallyfor the longer/more specific url's). But, for staff who are familiar with our product categories, it is a convenient way to find stuff, and easier to type! And for the simpler queries, the url's are pretty :) Thanks again!