# how to change basic url into seo friendly url in opencart

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, opencart

I had open the seo url in opencart 2.2.0 but it does not change the basic url into seo friendly url. when ever i click on any it shows the url something like that.

for index link --->

```
 http://homemartz.pk/index.php?route=common/home
```

product page link-->

```
http://homemartz.pk/index.php?route=product/product&path=76&product_id=105
```

and so on....
someone kindly help me to resolve this issue

Comment: So you tagged htaccess. Then you propably know which direction to go. Use google first, come back to SO once you stuck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess pretty url problem (mod\_rewrite)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138086/htaccess-pretty-url-problem-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

Go into your admin then settings and store and click on the server tab and tick Yes for use SEO urls.

Next rename htaccess.txt on to .htaccess in the root of the shop.

Make sure all products have a unique seo keyword on the products add/edit page.

Answer (score 0):

To set SEO URLS

1. Add the SEO keywords to all products and categories (unique
   keywords).
2. To set SEO URLs - Go to System>Settings>Server>Use SEO URLs. You only
   get this option on the DEFAULT store.
3. In your main OpenCart directory, there should be a file called .htaccess.txt. Rename it to .htaccess. If you already have an .htaccess file, Edit the .htaccess file.

> RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?*route*=$1 [L,QSA]

Also, refer link [Enable SEO friendly URLs in Opencart](http://themes.eshopalot.com/enable-seo-friendly-urls-in-opencart/)

Comment: I have previously changed all the things you have mentioned but it did not work yet.

Answer (score 0):

> You can follow below link for SEO friendly url in opencart

```
http://docs.opencart.com/administration/seo/
```